# Immutablejs not found default value

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm wondering when I get a deeply nested variable from an immutable map whether to set a default value of null or leave it and let it assign 'undefined' if not found.

The thing is that I almost always code in the following way (unless boolean or number variables):

```
const id = 2;
const item = state.getIn(['items', id]);
if (item) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Therefore I was under the impression that it doesn't matter whether I do as written above or:

```
const id = 2;
const item = state.getIn(['items', id], null);
if (item) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: What's your question? It will work fine in both ways and there is not a better way between those two, it's actually the same.

Comment: @Facundo well I guess I have to disagree with you that they are the same. Yes the code behaves the same but a lot of people have a strong opinion of what null means and what undefined means and when to use them. I'm just not good enough with those things :)

Comment: The only fact here is that the two pieces of code you bring behave the same way. My opinion is that `undefined` is better suited here because the value you are looking for is not defined. I think `null` is a better value for example when you expect a value and for some reason you can't return that value. For example if you make the `dequeue` method of a queue and you have no more elements, so you return null.